# IDEA is not showing compilation errors

Tags: intellij-idea

Suddenly my IDEA stopped showing compilation errors and it is kind of "Analyzing..." the code forever (as you can see on the top right)

- Power Safe mode is off
- Source folder is properly set
- JDK is set

Any idea what might be happening?

[image]

[image]

Logs: [idea.log](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aKBv1rse-mfYOsvXIbfSsDxUaOLdekgu?usp=sharing)

Comment: does `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` fix the issue?

Comment: @MarcoLucidi no, forgot to mention but that was my first try

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: @y.bedrov - logs added

Comment: @VeryNiceArgumentException Is it possible to share full log after restarting IDE?

Comment: @y.bedrov - sure. Could you tell what the best way to share such a big file like idea.log here. Same way I did for the logs above?

Comment: @VeryNiceArgumentException You may use any online service (e.g. dropbox)

Comment: @y.bedrov - added! (and thanks for the hint on using online service)

Comment: Are you using an Android project or Java project?

Comment: @GenoChen - it is a Java project, an Intellij plugin to be more precise. That's why maybe you are seeing Android classes around the log

Comment: @VeryNiceArgumentException Please try to temporarily disable custom plugins: 2020-12-16 09:56:59,940 [   1961]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: convert yaml to properties (1.0.1), Rainbow CSV (2.0), CSV Plugin (2.14.3), Builder Generator (1.1.8), FitNesse (1.11.0), Generate Tests (1.0.2), Lombok (0.32-EAP), Gauge (203.5981.155), Codota (4.2.2), JBehave Support (1.53), Gherkin (203.5981.155), Cucumber for Java (203.5981.155) 
and bundled "Android" plugin.

Comment: Disabling and enabling the Android plugin fixed the issue. Thanks guys!